# Removing objects from array onPress in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, object, calendar

My scope is to get max of five dates from the user, by on pressing on each dates at calendar. For example user can click on 5 dates on calendar, and also if the user represses on the selected date, then the selection should be removed, so that user can again click on one date.

I am using react-native-calendars, to show calendar, and achieved the selection of date process by saving the date in state. But, couldn't figure out how to remove the selected date from the state if the user represses on the selected Date.

Here is my code:

```
class PausePlan extends Component {

onPressSelectionHandler(day) { 
    this.setState((prevState) => ({selectedDateByOnPress: [...prevState.selectedDateByOnPress, day ], daysing: day}));     
}

state={selectedDateByOnPress: [], selected: false, daysing: ""}
render () {
    const selectedDate = _.uniqBy(this.state.selectedDateByOnPress, function(e){
        return e;
    });
    const date = format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    const addingDate = format(addDays(new Date(date), 30), 'YYYY-MM-DD');
    return (
        <Container>
            <View style={{ paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 60 }}>
                <H1>Plan Status</H1>
            </View>


        <View style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
            <Calendar 
            minDate={date}
            maxDate={addingDate}
            onDayPress={(day) => {
                this.onPressSelectionHandler(day)
            }}
            markedDates={selectedDate.reduce((acc, {dateString}) => {
                acc[dateString] = { selected: dateString === this.state.daysing ? true : false, color: '#22a6b3'};
                return acc;
                },
              {}
            )}
            markingType={'period'}
            />
        </View>
        </Container>
    );
}
};
```

By using above code, if user press on a date, it gets selected and i am setting this in my state using onpress handler. But, if user repress on the same selected date, the selected date should be un-selected and also it should be updated in state (as the calendar rerender if state changes).

How can i do this ? Please guide me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if `selectedDateByOnPress` already includes `day`. If yes, `filter` it out. Else, add it to the array:

```js
this.setState((prevState) => ({
      selectedDateByOnPress: 
          [...(prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.some(d => d.dateString === day.dateString) 
                 ? prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.filter(d => d.dateString !== day.dateString) 
                 : [...prevState.selectedDateByOnPress, day])
          ],
      daysing: day
    }))
```

Comment: No, i have tried this, but now its adding the days over the array if we repress on this (this was the same happened in my code ). And, by repress on selected date its its keeping on adding it to the array, but the date is not unseleted ( i meant the date is not removed from the state )

Comment: What is the type of `day`? From the `daysing: ""` code, I assumed it was a string

Comment: while console.loging the day , this is the value "{year: 2019, month: 2, day: 13, timestamp: 1550016000000, dateString: "2019-02-13"}", as i am getting this from the calendar inbuilt onpress function

Comment: Updated the asnwer

Comment: OMG, hats off @Adiga, i have been struggling with this for more than 6 hours. Your definitely a genius ! Bowing head :)

Comment: One last question, can is there any possible to limit the entries to max of 5 ? I mean, the allowed date selection is not more than 5, so is there any possible way to limit this ?

Comment: Inside `onPressSelectionHandler` call `setState` only if `this.state.selectedDateByOnPress.length < 5`

Comment: this.state.selectedDateByOnPress.length < 5 ?
        this.setState((prevState) => ({selectedDateByOnPress: [...(prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.some(d => d.dateString === day.dateString) 
            ? prevState.selectedDateByOnPress.filter(d => d.dateString !== day.dateString) 
            : [...prevState.selectedDateByOnPress, day])
     ], daysing: day})) : this.setState({ showing: 'flex' })     , what happening is after selecting 5 dates, it automatically moves to next condition so, if again press on selected date its not unselecting !

Comment: When , i set the condition. the execution stops by the condition, after length of 5 i couldnt un-select the date. I dont know whats stopping this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187990/discussion-between-adiga-and-arvindh).